# Property access must assign to the property or use its value

Tags: vb.net

Need help on this.

I find it weird that this error occured when I don't have any properties assigned in the class. Below is my source code.

```
    Public Function GenerateNonContainerReport(ByVal dateFrom As Date, ByVal dateTo As Date, ByVal userID As String) As rptNonContainerized
    Try
        Dim dtNonContainer As New dsPrint.dtNonContainerDataTable

        Dim strSQL As String = "EXEC dbo.sp_RetrieveNonContainerizedRev @StartDate=" + dateFrom + ", @EndDate=" + dateTo + ", @UserID=" + userID

        myConnectionSettings = New ConnectionStringSettings("SQLConnection", strConn, "System.Data.SqlClient")
        myProvider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(myConnectionSettings.ProviderName)
        db = New GenericDatabase(myConnectionSettings.ConnectionString, myProvider)
        dbCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand(strSQL)

        Dim dTable = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand).Tables(0) ' error occurs here

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
    End Sub
```

The application is using an xsd file which stores the data tables. Moreover, this stored procedure accepts 3 parameters. Is it possible that the error occurs here?

**LATEST UPDATE** 
I got this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I'm now wondering where in the code I did not instantiate.

Comment: the error occurs when the data is being passed in the data table.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DataSet has tables returned

```
dataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand) 'Break here and inspect the object
```

Look for dataSet.Tables

Also,

- Don't New the DataTable
- Don't use pascal notation eg strSQL -> sql
- Watch out for SQL injections
- Don't eat exceptions
- Dispose in the finally

Comment: I'll revise the code for easier reading.

Moreover, I don't see any relationship with the error and the pascal notation since the user can declare any variable name.

Comment: I checked the code and it seems that there's an error when assigning it to the specific parameters. What's the best thing to do?